# Why displaying PUSH rather than STM when CPU is in ARM mode?

Tags: assembly, arm, embedded

I'm debugging on Code Composer Studio from Texas Instruments, and noticed that there is a push instruction displayed on disassembly view **when CPU is in the ARM mode**.

According to [ARM and Thumb Assembler Instructions](http://engold.ui.ac.ir/~nikmehr/Appendix_B1.pdf):

> PUSH Pushes multiple registers to the stack in Thumb state (for ARM
>   state use STM)

Q1: Why is push instruction displayed rather than STM?

I also noticed that before program starts running, the stack pointer's value had been set already.

Q2: The value of stack pointer is decided by who?

Program:

```
int main(void)
{   // program stops here

    OS_ERR  err = OS_ERR_NONE;

    /*rest of code are omitted*/
}
```

Disassembly:

```
          main():
805dce18:   E92D4008            push       {r3, lr}
17          OS_ERR  err = OS_ERR_NONE;
805dce1c:   E3A0C000            mov        r12, #0
805dce20:   E58DC000            str        r12, [sp]
```

Registers:

```
Name    Value            Description

CPSR    0x6000019F       current program status registers
   T    0                If set ARM is in Thumb mode



  SP    0x88000F30       stack pointer
```

Comment: A1) is just a friendly service of your disassembler. Note that the official material recommends using `push` and that's probably why the disassembler shows the `stmdb` as `push` too. A2) whoever called your `main` already set it up. As to whether it's random, I don't know. If your OS is not running yet, then it's probably not random.

Comment: The SP register gets initialized by the startup code (e.g. C runtime initialization) before main() gets called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Q2) The Stack Pointer initialization location is in your binary file. The first four bytes in your output binary denotes the location to which the stack pointer is to be initialized. You can modify this value as well as the size of the stack in your linker file.

Answer (score 2):

For Q1) Notice that the link you gave is for **ARMv6 architecture**.
Be careful if your situation is held on that case.

Also, [Arm Information Center](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489e/Babefbce.html) gives an answer:

> PUSH is a synonym for STMDB sp!, reglist and POP is a synonym for
>   LDMIA sp! reglist. PUSH and POP are the preferred mnemonics in these
>   cases.

If you want to check the whole discussion about this question, please refer to [here](https://e2e.ti.com/support/tools/ccs/f/81/t/773689) in TI's discussion forum.